# Creating a scatter plot in matlab with different colors and markers for two different grouping variables

Tags: matlab, grouping, scatter-plot

I seem to be having problems creating a 2D scatter plot in matlab with two grouping variables which displays different colors for one of them and different markers for the other. The variable "score" has the X and Y values and the two grouping variables are "att21" and "att22".

I use the following code:

```
f=figure;
gscatter(score(:,1), score(:,2), {att21, att22}, 'br', 'xo');
```

what I'm getting is: 
[scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kucFX.jpg)

However, what I want to get is blue for L4 and red for L1 and x for Flake and o for Chunk. I would also like the legend to indicate this.

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

When you are grouping by 2 grouping variables, each with 2 categories, you are implicitly creating 4 different groups, so you have to define the color and markers for the 4 groups, in your case

```
gscatter(score(:,1), score(:,2), {att21, att22}, 'rrbb', 'xoxo');
```

But since `gscatter` will repeat the pattern if the defined color or marker is smaller than the number of groups, you can save 2 characters by doing

```
gscatter(score(:,1), score(:,2), {att21, att22}, 'rrbb', 'xo');
```

---

If you don't know the number of groups in each category, you can obtain them with the command `unique` and count them, and then use that number to create the markers and colors. For your example

```
marker = '+o*.xsd';
clr = 'rgbymck';

n_groups_att1 = length(unique(att21));
n_groups_att2 = length(unique(att22));

m = marker(1:n_groups_att2);

c = repmat(clr(1:n_groups_att1),n_groups_att2,1);
c = c(:)';

gscatter(score(:,1), score(:,2), {att21, att22}, c, m);
```

Just make sure that `marker` and `clr` has more elements than possible number of groups in each grouping variable

Comment: @G.Herzlinger glad I could help, please set your question as answered so it can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured it out. The solution provided by Noel is good only if I know the number of groups in each grouping variable, but unfortunately this is not the case.

So I came up with the solution if using nested loops.

```
f=figure;
hold on;
marker = '+o*.xsd';
clr = 'rgbymck';

att1v = unique(att1);
att2v = unique(att2);
attv = [att1v; att2v];
att1count = 1;
att2count = 1;

for k=1:length(score)
    att1count = 1;
    att2count = 1;
    while att1count <= length(att1v)
        if isequal(att1(k),att1v(att1count))
            while att2count <= length(att2v)
                if isequal(att2(k),att2v(att2count))
                    f=scatter(score(k,1),score(k,2),15,clr(att1count),marker(att2count));

                end
                att2count = att2count + 1;
            end
        end
        att1count = att1count + 1;
    end
end
legend(attv);
```

Now the scatter plot is OK and its supports up to 7 groups in each variable. The only problem I'm left with is that I can't manage to create a Legend which shows the different labels for all the groups.

All I manage to get is this:[plot with bad legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jyu6.jpg)

If anyone has a solution for me it will be great...

Thanks alot

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include the case when you don't know the number of groups. It is better to work on creating the markers and color strings, so `gscatter` handles the legend.